# Laravel Eloquent ignore attribute if not in table during insert

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model Foo that corresponds to a table with the following columns.

id
description
user_id

I'm setting the attributes of the Foo model individually (no mass assignment)

```
$foo = new Foo;

$foo->id = 1;
$foo->description = "hello kitty";
$foo->user_id = 55;

//...
```

$foo is sent to another class for additional processing, but because that class needs a bit more information, I would like to simply add it to the $foo model.

```
//...
$foo->bar = $additional_information;

Event::fire(DoStuffWithFoo($foo));

$foo->save();  //error
```

the problem is when I `$foo->save()`, it complains that `bar` isn't a column.

I know I can `unset($foo->bar);` before saving, but...

Is it possible to tell Eloquent to simply ignore any non relevant attributes?

Comment: I think the $fillable variable of Eloquent can help you like here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620364/can-eloquent-ignore-irrelevant-data-in-laravel-4

Comment: I saw that, but I thought $fillable was just for mass assignment.  Which guess I could just create an array and pass that in instead of assigning each attribute individually...  `$foo = new Foo($array);`

Answer (score 48):

Just add `$bar` as an attribute in your foo class:

```
class Foo extends Model
{

  public $bar;
  //...
```

now you can use `save()` and Laravel will not try to store `bar` in the DB.

---

Explanation:

If you call `save()` on a model, only those attributes that are in the array `$model->attributes` will be saved to the database. If you define `$bar` as an attribute in the class `Foo`, then `$foo->bar ="xyz"` will never end up in the array `$model->attributes`.

However, if you do not have declared such an attribute for `Foo`, then `__set()` is called because you [try to save something in an inaccessible property](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

You may check out `Laravel\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php`:

```
/**
     * Dynamically set attributes on the model.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
```

which basically calls

```
$this->attributes[$key] = $value;
```

from  `Laravel\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php`.

Now `$foo->bar ="xyz"` will end up beeing in `$foo->attribute['bar']` and this is why `save()` crashes with `..this column does not exists..`.

Comment: i want this to work for me but it just wont. i have an attribute thats not on the table but is a getBarAttribute. no matter what i try when i call $model->save() it will NOT let me get around this attribute not being on the table.

Comment: @caro^can you provide example code?

Answer (score 6):

I understand this question is old but it was in top results for a recent search where I was trying to solve a similar problem and I think that this may be an ideal case for Laravel accessors/mutators. I have tested this on Laravel 5.6 but believe it may work as far back as 4.2.

By creating a mutator and accessor rather than a public property it will allow adding the field to fillable for mass assignment while still excluding it from the internal attributes (thus preventing it from errantly saving to the DB). I understand the original request excluded mass-assignment but that doesn't necessarily exclude this answer. I think an example will help:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    //Allow bar in mass assignment
    protected $fillable = [
            "bar"
        ];

    /**
     * Store bar in protected variable instead of attributes
     * Because bar is not set in attributes, Laravel will not try to save it to database
     */
    protected $bar;

    /**
     * Mutator method to set bar's value
     */
    public function setBarAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->bar = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method to retrieve bar's value
     */ 
    public function getBarAttribute()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

When this model is created using mass-assignment the mutator (setBarAttribute) method will be called for bar if it exists in the mass-assigned values. Anytime the bar property is accessed the respective get/set method will be called. Because the mutator does not set the value of bar in the model's internal attributes variable the model will not save bar to the database.

Comment: Confirmed, setting the mutator helps in not trying to save this attribute to the database. Thank you :)

Comment: Mutators are unnecessary if you set variable to public. Also you don't need to put it in $fillable

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late, but you can register the `saving` operation by override the `boot` function in your model:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($model) {
        $savable = [...];
        if (count($savable) > 0) {
            $model->attributes = array_intersect_key($model->attributes, array_flip($savable));
        }
    });
}
```

This is untested code, but the idea is to remove the attributes that have not intersect with the variable `savable` before saving the model. The variable `savable` is an array of the savable attributes. For example `$savable = ['foo', 'bar']` will save only the `foo` and `bar` attributes.

Pros: You can mass assign any attributes that you want without harm to `fillable` or `guarded`.

Cons: The attributes that are not marked as `savable`, will be deleted from the model after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue: needed to store temporary value in model just to be passed to event (e.g. plain password that had to be mailed to user on registration but not stored anywhere).

Solved by adding **public $plain_password;** to model class.

*No mutators of $fillable modifications needed.*

Comment: This is literally the first line of the top answer. "Just add $bar as an attribute in your foo class"

Answer (score -1):

Add the $fillable and the model will ignore everything not in it (instead of giving an error). Using the constructor function to fill all the columns is optional.

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'description', 'user_id'];
}

$f = new Foo(['id' => 1, 'description' => "hello monkey", 'user_id' => 55, 'bar' => 'wow']); // should work w/o error, but it ignores the 'bar'.
```

Comment: Looks like using `$fillable` not only prevents any attempt to save that value to the DB, but it also keeps the attribute from being set in the first place.  So in other words it won't quite work since I need that attribute to be passed to another class, but just not saved.

Answer (score -2):

If you add an attribute through

```
$model->foo = "Some data";
```

Then before saving, update the model data with

```
$model->refresh()
```

This will update all model data from the database and reset all assigned variables

Comment: This is not a valid solution - calling `refresh()` will reset any changes you've made, and calling `save()` afterwards would therefore be pointless. Not to mention this will introduce an extra database query for the `refresh()`.