# How to custom new property with Eloquent Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel

I use below script to update an existed post model:

```
$post = Post::find($postId);
$post->title = $title;
$post->description = $description;
$post->save();
```

But I would like to store `old_title` attribute for another process only in `Post` object, so I add `$post->old_title = $post->title` before reset the title. Then the script looks like:

```
$post = Post::find($postId);
$post->old_title = $post->title;
$post->title = $title;
$post->description = $description;
$post->save();
// Another process
```

So I got error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'old_title' in 'field list'`
How to ignore this attribute?
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380752/laravel-eloquent-ignore-attribute-if-not-in-table-during-insert

Comment: "But I would like to store old_title attribute for another process only in Post object" what does that actually mean?

Comment: - include old_title in the guarded array, so  it will be blacklisted.

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq  `guarded` and `fillable` only come into play for mass assignment

Answer (score 1):

This will let u add another properties for the model other than the columns in db

```
class MODEL_NAME extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'TABLE_NAME';
    protected $appends = array('APPENDED_VALUES');

}
```

Comment: this just appends something to the serialized output, where would the value come from? and how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you **edit the migration of the post model** and **add the "old_title" field in the database table** and try to **update the old_title** value with that of the **$post->title**. 
It will help you track the update pattern of the user and do some operation to that.

Answer (score 0):

After long time work with Laravel, I found `getOriginal()` function from `HasAttributes` trait, which is included in Eloquent model.
By using saved model object `$post` (don't call `$post->fresh()`), I can retrieve old title of the post

```
  $oldTitle = $post->getOriginal('title');
```