# Laravel 8: appended field but still receiving "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hello' in 'field list'"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model: `Users`

I must append an attribute `hello` to it which will contain arbitrary data. I am using the following code:

```php
...
class Users extends Model  {
   ...

   protected $appends = ['hello'];
}
```

Problem is whenever I save/update the model I receive the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_data' in 'field list'

I understand Laravel attempts to update the column in database and it's natural it can't because it's a virtual attribute. But how can I prevent that from happening? It's annoying it occurs on both `save()` and `update()` on queries which have nothing to do with the attribute, such as:

```php
$Model->update(['username' => 'some username']);
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it! Quodos to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970224/8555937

I don't need to append it, I must declare it within model first and Eloquent will ignore it:

```php
...
class Users extends Model  {
   ...

   public $hello;
}
```