# Can eloquent ignore irrelevant data in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

This is basically the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620364/can-eloquent-ignore-irrelevant-data-in-laravel-4) here from 2013. Except the answer doesn't work for me.

I have a Model App\Post:

```php
 class Post extends Model
 {
   protected $fillable = ['title'];
   // This Model doesn't contain an 'authorname' field
   public function author()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
   }
 }
```

and a Model App\Author:

```php
 class Author extends Model
 {
   protected $fillable = ['name'];

   public function posts()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
   }
 }
```

And an array I want to save to that Model:

```php
$posts = [
   ['title'=>'one post', 'authorname' => 'Mickey'],
   ['title'=>'another post', 'authorname' => 'Minny'],
];

foreach($posts as $post){
   $authorModel=App\Author::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$post['authorname']]);
   App\Post::create($post)->author()->associate($authorModel)->save();
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620364/can-eloquent-ignore-irrelevant-data-in-laravel-4) question, that should work, but I get an

> SQL error 42522: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'authorname' in 'field list'

which suggests Laravel forwards the whole array to mySQL. Is there a way to make this work without unsetting the authorname key?

Obviously this is a simpified version of what I want to do and keeping track of what to unset seems unnecessary - as would be assigning all array keys to their respective database fields manually.

Comment: Please post the whole error message with the executed query.

Comment: You are looping over `$post`, right? `$post['authorname']` wouldn't work like this.

Comment: My bad. Cut too much out. Corrected...

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir: The whole error I get is: `In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'authorname' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into 'posts' ('name', 'authorname', 'updat  
  ed_at', 'created_at') values (Frau Meier, die Amsel, Kathrin Leuenberger, 2018-12-11 16:05:28, 2018-12-11 16:05:28))                         

In Connection.php line 452:
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'authorname' in 'field list'`

Comment: Do your `posts` table contains `authorname` column? Because you have: `App\Post::create($post)` where $post variable has that field ...

Comment: no it does not. That is exactly the question: Can Eloquent Ignore Irrelevant Data.

Comment: Are you overriding `$guarded` in the `Post` model? Are you using any additional packages? What's the result of `dd((new Post($post))->getAttributes());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea I have here is that you run this code in DatabaseSeeder (which automatically unguards models) or you somewhere manually call `Eloquent::unguard()` (or code similar to this). This would explain why any other fields are used when creating model no matter of `$fillable` property.

Comment: My (copied from somewhere) seeder code was surrounded with unguard//guard the models. To test, if this was the problem, I commented them out - didn't realize, seeders do unguard per default.

Comment: this also make fillable model to be asterisk, how about the specific to ignore unknown column on saving